# How to only scrape unique links with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape only unique links off a webpage using python and write the urls to a csv file. The code I have so far scrapes the links, but it has duplicate links in the file.

For example, the csv file has one url twice, with the second having a / at the very end. I thought

```
if link.endswith('/'):
        link = link[-1]
```

would remove it, but I'm pretty new to python, so maybe I did something wrong or am misunderstanding something.

But in addition to that, I do have some urls that are exactly the same, no backslash or anything different and they also appear in the document. If I'm way off base with my code, I'd love to understand more about how to remove these links as I'm lost. Is there a good tutorial online somewhere that someone could recommend?

Or maybe it's a simple fix that I'm overlooking?? I'll post the full code below. Thank you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url="https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest"

r=requests.get(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

results =  soup.find_all("a")

for link in results:
link.get("href")       

def unique_urls(tags,url):
cleaned_urls = set()

for link in results:
link = link.get("href")

    if link is None:
        continue
    if link.endswith('/'):
        link = link[-1]

    actual_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,link)
    cleaned_urls.add(actual_url)

return cleaned_urls

print(cleaned_urls)


import csv
for link in results:
S=link.get('href')
csvRow = [S]
csvfile = "urls1.csv"
with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(csvRow )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct to use a `set` to find the unique items.  If you want to put your urls in a common format, checkout the [url-normalize](https://pypi.org/project/url-normalize] library.  There are probably others.  Many won't remove trailing slashes, however, as those could have meaning.  You can remove a final character with `link[:-1]` (not `link[-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

The link you are trying to scrape is no longer available, give us another link with urls so I can provide the code.

Anyway, I guess you have 2 issues: removing duplicates from collected data and stored this data into csv.

**1. removing duplicates from collected data:**
When you get the urls stored in a list, to remove duplicate, you just need to convert the list to set then convert it to a list: **list -> set -> list**

```
list_of_urls = ['url_1', 'url_1', 'url_2', 'url_1', 'url_1', 'url_2', 'url_3', 'url_3'] 
set_of_urls = set(list_of_urls) # return : {'url_1', 'url_2', 'url_3'}
list_clean = list(set_of_urls) # return :['url_3', 'url_1', 'url_2']

# or directly: list_clean = list(set(list_of_urls))
```

**2. Store clean data into csv file:**

This is a clean approach, step by step:
Suppose that you only need to store emails, this means 1 columns in our csv file

```
with open('emails.csv', 'w') as csv_file:       #create a file called emails.csv and open it in write mode  / csv_file = file-like object
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, lineterminator='\n')    # create the writer(csv file), which will write rows one by one on the csv_file (Return a writer object)
    header = ['emails']   
    w.writerow(header)      # .writerow(list) : get list and add it to the table as row

    for email in list_clean : #list_clean is the list of emails already collected
        # each loop create 1 row: val1, val2 val3
        w.writerow(['email'])     #.writerow(list) each row on each loop will be added to the file (row must be an iterable of strings or numbers)
```

If you want to store your data in a **text file** (1 columns no need to be in csv):

```
with open('emails.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in list_clean:     
        f.write("%s\n" % i)
```

Comment: Sorry, the url is https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html. I took off the .html part for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: What is exactly the data you want to collect from this website ?  Just the urls from this web page?

Comment: I'm trying to scrape only unique urls and save them as absolute urls in the csv file. Unfortunately, my code is bringing in a few dupes as well as it is still bringing in relative urls instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a simple library.

```
import csv
from simplified_scrapy import req, SimplifiedDoc
url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest'
html = req.get(url)
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lstA = doc.listA(url=url) # This is the result of de duplication
csvRow = [a.url for a in lstA]

csvfile = "urls1.csv"
with open(csvfile, "a") as fp:
  wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
  wr.writerow(csvRow )
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples